# Android - How to work around a "no space left on device" error

Tags: android, out-of-memory, ioexception

So my latest app runs into this problem where it complains in the logcat that theres no room left on the device to save files but that is definitely not the case as I can close my app open the stock camera and take a picture. How has everybody else dealt with this problem.

Edit: The error occurs in this method

```
    private void writeFile(Bitmap bmp, File f) {
    FileOutputStream out = null;

    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(f);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 80, out);//<---error here
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.w("nullpointerException on image error", "nullpointer");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.w("fileNotfoundException on image error", "filenotfound");
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally { 
        try { if (out != null ) out.close(); }
        catch(Exception ex) {} 
    }
}
```

and this is the logcat report on this error:

```
java.io.IOException: no space left on device
at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.write(Native Method)
at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedFileSystem.write(BlockGuard.java:171)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:300)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCompress(Native Method)
at data.ImageManager.writeFile(ImageManager.java:215)
at data.ImageManager.getBitmap(ImageManager.java:192)
at data.ImageManager.access$1(ImageManger.java:102)
at data.ImageManager$ImageQueueManager.run(ImageManager.java:290)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Edit: Heres how I though you create a directory on external memory

This is what Im using to create the place that I thought would be the sd card

```
    String sdState = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (sdState.equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        File sdDir = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();      
        cacheDir = new File(sdDir,"data/gr");
    }
    else
        cacheDir = context.getExternalCacheDir();

    if(!cacheDir.exists())
        cacheDir.mkdirs();


    if(sdState.equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
        File adSdDir =     android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        adCacheDir = new File(adSdDir,"data/ad");
    }else
        adCacheDir = context.getExternalCacheDir();

    if(!adCacheDir.exists())
        adCacheDir.mkdirs();
}
```

and then in the method that I look for or create the image to go into the directory:

```
 private Bitmap getBitmap(ImgRequestObj ids) {
    String url = null;
    String filename = ids.objId.toString();
    File f = null;

    try{
        if(ids.objName.equals("mark")){
            url = graffMarksURL;
            f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
        }else if(ids.objName.equals("admark")){
            url = adMarksURL;
            f = new File(adCacheDir, filename);
        }



    // Is the bitmap in our cache?
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getPath());
    if(bitmap != null) return bitmap;

    // Nope, have to download it
    try {   
            BitmapFactory.Options bfOptions=new BitmapFactory.Options();

            bfOptions.inDither=false;                     //Disable Dithering mode

            bfOptions.inPurgeable=true;                   //Tell to gc that whether it needs free memory, the Bitmap can be cleared

            bfOptions.inInputShareable=true;              //Which kind of reference will be used to recover the Bitmap data after being clear, when it will be used in the future


            DefaultHttpClient client;
            HttpResponse response = null;
            HttpParams params = null;// new Http parameters to be used for extra buffering room in VM
            HttpPost post = null;
            InputStream is = null;
            BufferedInputStream bis = null;
            Bitmap bmp = null;
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nvp1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            nvp1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", ids.objId.toString()));
            // - martin passing id to php script select statement
             client = new DefaultHttpClient();

            try {

                post = new HttpPost(url);
                params = post.getParams();//Setting the new Http params to post
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvp1));
                try{
                HttpConnectionParams.setSocketBufferSize(params, 8192);//Defining the new buffer size
                response = client.execute(post);

                }
                catch(HttpResponseException e){
                    e.getCause();
                                    }
            //Capture response from query and prepare as input
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            // move content to Input Stream
                is = entity.getContent();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

                bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                try{
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis, null, bfOptions);
                }finally{}

                    if( is != null )
                        try {
                            is.close();
                            //response = null;
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    //Log.w("inputstream of image closed", "for this image "+id.toString());
                    if( bis != null )
                        try {
                            //response = null;
                            bis.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    bitmap = bmp;
                    writeFile(bitmap, f);
                    try{
                        bmp = null;
                    }catch(NullPointerException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return bitmap;}
                catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return bitmap;
    }catch(NullPointerException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
        }
```

Comment: and how are you preparing `File f`?

Comment: How are you building the path to file f? If you are not careful, you could be using internal storage which could be filling up without affecting the platform camera.

Comment: Im using the code up above that I added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are actually using internal memory by using `getCacheDir()` in your else statement. However, if you want to store large data then its recommended to use `getExternalCacheDir()` because not all android phones have huge internal storage, but they do/may have bigger external storage.

```
if (sdState.equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) { 
   File sdDir = context.getExternalCacheDir();
   cacheDir = new File(sdDir,"data"); 
} 
else 
   Log.e("storage", "SD card not found");
```

Comment: That didnt work :( I erased all the data for my app and uninstalled it and then using what you suggested I tried running it but it still ends up creating the files on the internal memory. Also as soon as the images are up to about 60 I couldnt take a picture again.

Comment: are you using `getExternalCacheDir()` this time?

Comment: just replace all your getCacheDir() with getExternalCacheDir() and give a shot

Comment: Hey thanks for the push in the right direction. I ended up using this to make it work....---> context.getExternalFilesDir(sdState);

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing my code where I create my directories to the following:

```
  String sdState = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (sdState.equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        File sdDir = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();      
        cacheDir = new File(sdDir,"data/gr");
    }
    else
        cacheDir = context.getExternalFilesDir(sdState); <--changed

    if(!cacheDir.exists())
        cacheDir.mkdirs();


    if(sdState.equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
        File adSdDir = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        adCacheDir = new File(adSdDir,"data/ad");
    }else
        adCacheDir = context.getExternalFilesDir(sdState); <--changed

    if(!adCacheDir.exists())
        adCacheDir.mkdirs();
}
```

So far using this I am able to once again save images I take with the camera with all the images in my area download.