# java.io.IOException: No space left on device Android

Tags: java, android, io, filesystems, ioexception

We have application on android market, our users getting a lot from this error:
**java.io.IOException: No space left on device**

From what I found out so far, I know that they got enough space left on they external storage, and it's only happen on Android 2.x .

I had a small research in Linux file system, and I found out that beyond the space limitation there are limitation on number of files in each directory and the total number of files under root directory. But it looks like our app is not hitting any of those.

- Have you ever run in two some thing like that?
- Any ideas about what changed in Android (2.x) and how they fix it in Android (3+)?

**Edit:** this is not installation problem, but when trying to save downloaded files.

Comment: Does your app download a lot of files in the android internal storage? If so then refer to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320070/android-how-to-work-around-a-no-space-left-on-device-error

Comment: @sultan.of.swing Nope this is not it, I did from beginning what he found to be the right way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

adding a loging-output of the absolute filepath, that caused the exception might help.

if the file beeing written was written to local memory file-system and not to sd-card-filesystem here is a possible solution:

`java.io.IOException: No space left on device` my mean that there is not enought memory left on the **internal storage file system** of the device.

You can try to **install** the app **on the sd-card** instead by setting an entry in the manifest-file:

```
  <manifest ..... android:installLocation="preferExternal">
```

Edit

if an app is installed in internal memory it-s local files are stored in local memory, too.
if an app is installed on sd-cardit it-s local files are stored on sd-card, too.

so installing the app on sd-card might solve your problem.

Comment: It looks like you didn't understand the question. I add an edit for you. Please read it again, this is defiantly not a problem of space, we checked it.

Comment: i updated the answer. can you add the filepath to your qestion?

Answer (score 0):

I believe (if I'm not correct) that it could be having trouble opening a big file or any file that goes over the max of the eternal storage after all the space is used up. For example: My android didn't have any problems opening up until after I used all of the space on my device til the very last bit. Unless I upgrade or delete all of my fav songs and movies it won't work. Tested and tried it. But then again the error could be more flexible and mean something else as well... :D